# Is it possible to write a convolution as a sum?

Tags: convolution

**Problem:**
Let $f, a$ be functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous.
Assume that the convolution $g=f*a$ is well defined, i.e. $g(x)=\int_{t\in \mathbb R} f(t)a(x-t)dt<\infty$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. I am interested in rewriting $g$ as a sum of  $a$ functions, i.e. are there exits $t_1, ..., t_n$ such that $g(x)=\sum_{i=1,...,n} a(x-t_i)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

**My guess** is that it is impossible. Because I observe that if

- If $a$ is discontinuous, $g$ is still continuous.
- If $a$ is continuous, $g$ is differentiable
- If $a$ is $k$-diffrentiable then $g$ is $(k+1)$-differentiable for $k\geq 1$

So I guess that the answer is impossible. But how to formalize my idea if it is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly disprove the general assertion by inspecting a case like $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $a(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }\lvert x\rvert\ge1\\ e^{(x^2-1)^{-1}}&\text{if }\lvert x\rvert<1\end{cases}$. Then, $f*a(x)>0$ for all $x$, but all finite sums of translations of $a$ have compact support.

Comment: $f(x) = 1$ works just as well, and is a bit simpler

Comment: @SolubleFish Agreed, but I wanted $f\in\bigcap_{p\in [1,\infty]}L^p(\Bbb R)$ because I wanted to avoid a shower of what-ifs.

Comment: @Gae.S. ah yes, thank you for your elegant example!